# Optimal arrangement of alphabet for boggle-type game

Tags: combinatorics

This question was posed to me, and my first thought was the answer has probably already been found. However, I cannot find it.

If you were to arrange the alphabet (minus the Q) in a 5x5 array, what arrangement would allow you to find the most words in the grid (first, only going left-right and up-down, but the problem can be relaxed to allow for right-left, down-up, and even non-linear arrangements such as
ma
sp
generating "maps" (and "a" and "spam" etc.)

The number of possible words in the simplest version of the problem is 103 (accounting for the fact there are only 3 one-letter words, which will always be present), but the number of arrangements of letters is 25!

What would be the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: The heart of this problem is not really mathematical.  It depends on the caprices of spelling in the English language.  

There probably aren't a lot of improvements over the brute force (computerized) search, which is pretty much guaranteed to be intractable because of the size of $25! \approx 10^{25}$.